# What is the shelf life of HEPA filters?

Tags: air-quality

I was not sure on which site to ask this question, but I guess Engineering might do well from the aspect of matter.

I am wondering, what is the shelf life of a HEPA filter, can I just buy a few of them for my air cleaner and let them sit in my drawer?

Comment: Don’t shops let them sit on their shelves? They should be fine...

Answer (score 1):

Air filters are made of fibrous material (paper typically) that is basically inert. There is no reason that storing it in a cool, dry place would cause it to expire.

The HEPA designation has more to deal with how the air flows through it rather than the material that it is made from